# Tag property is not identified in xml android application?

Tags: android

I tag property in xml webview control,coding is not getting tag property

xml file:

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_part"
        android:tag="xlarge-portrait" />
```

Code file:

```
 String tag = webview.getTag().toString();
 if (tag.equals("xlarge-portrait")) {
    webview.getSettings().setTextSize(TextSize.LARGER);
 } else {
    webview.getSettings().setTextSize(TextSize.NORMAL);
 }
```

Logs:

```
06-07 12:00:00.757: E/AndroidRuntime(7482): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-07 12:00:00.757: 
E/AndroidRuntime(7482): 
    at com.agility.agilitylogistics.postcontent_web_view.onCreate(postcontent_web_view.java:100)
```

How to resolve the issue?please send me any solution .

Comment: you are missing a closing quotation on android:tag to start with.

Comment: sorry i am edited the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing a closing quotation on android:tag to start with.

EDIT: Here is a the best way to get the tag in String. You need to String cast it as below:

```
String str=(String) webView.getTag();
```

Comment: for which line? you need to edit your original post with a bigger chunk of code and logs. It is very difficult to figure out the problem the way it looks right now

Comment: str return null can not identify the webview tag

Comment: Can you edit your code to show us how you are setting up the webView variable?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31378/discussion-between-kushyar-and-narasimha)

Comment: Hi Kushar issue clear its working fine another dependency,thank u very much for sharing information